# How to list conferences on a CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I am an undergraduate student in math.

I have attended a few conferences/workshops and was wondering what is the best way to distinguish between the following on my CV:

- conferences/workshops with only invited participation
- conferences/workshops where I applied for and received funding
- conferences/workshops where I only needed to register

or if such a distinction is even meaningful.

Comment: I usually lump-sum them under, "conference proceedings and workshops". I just add a "- invited"  or "- keynote speaker" in italics for those that I was invited to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction between a conference one **attends** and a conference one **is invited to speak at** is relevant at all levels of one's career in math.

If you don't give a talk, the distinction between a conference you *attend simply by registering* and a conference you attend *by invitation only* or *only if accepted* (like workshops at [AIM](http://aimath.org/workshops/), [Banff](http://www.birs.ca/programs/general-program-descriptions), or [Oberwolfach](http://www.mfo.de/scientific-programme/meetings/workshop))  usually isn't particularly important.

However, for an undergraduate to have been specifically invited to a invitation-only conference is rather unusual, and might indicate that you have a good reputation among senior mathematicians in the field, certainly a plus if applying to graduate school. If so, by *far* the most important way to communicate this in your file is by **getting a letter of recommendation from those senior mathematicians**. But it can't hurt to indicate it in your CV as well; in your "Conferences attended" section, just add a parenthetical "(invitation-only)" to the relevant entries.

But let me reiterate that what you put on your CV is **100 times less important** than getting a strong recommendation letter from senior mathematicians who know you well and think highly of your potential for research.